# I want to create an archive and single page for a custom taxonomy for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy

I have researched the heck out of this so forgive if I missed the answer somewhere...

I have registered a custom post type 'audiotalk'. Each talk can have one or more teachers so I registered a custom taxonomy for audiotalk called 'teacher' (non-heirachical).

I have an archive and single template for each audiotalk. I would like to find out if I can create an archive and single template for each teacher, with photo (I am using a plugin that associates an image with a taxonomy), description ($term->description) and that's pretty much it. The archive would simply be a list of teachers with links to their single page.

I've tried creating a single-teacher.php template but it's not working, meaning I am linking to, for example https://my.bodhitree.com/teacher/doreen-virtue/ and it's not using that template. In fact that page doesn't exist and I'm not sure why.

Can anybody enlighten me about what to do next?

Comment: did you do a permalink flush?  taxonomy would likely be a page called category-teacher.php if that is your category name.  needs to be specific to your name exactly though so make sure it's not just "teacher"

Comment: The permalinks flush got me part of the way there, thanks for that. Now something different that was broken is now working.

Comment: @rudtek unfortunately the 'teacher' taxonomy is only half working. I have a taxonomy-teacher.php template which is now working as a teacher archive, but single teacher pages are not working. single-teacher.php is not the trick, or my code is wrong.

Comment: There is no `single-teacher.php` template, that is for custom post types, not taxonomies. Taxonomies are used to group posts, so they only have archives for each term in the taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks @Milo that clears things up. I'm going to have to get creative to do what I need to do.

Comment: You could use the term archive for both purposes- put the teacher info/photo at the top or in a sidebar and then have the list of their talks below. You can use `get_queried_object()` to get the current teacher term data within the template.

Comment: @Milo I ended up doing just that, using the taxonomy archive as my single page and it worked out beautifully. So each teacher archive page (taxonomy-teacher.php) has their photo, bio, and a list of their audiotalks. It's actually just what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using archive page in this case taxonomy-teacher.php

That page will return all the terms so you need to use "`get_queried_object()`" which will only show the data of that particular post.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks @Faisal for your response. You are totally correct! But I had actually solved the issue in the comments (same solution as yours) so I couldn't mark it as resolved. I'll mark your answer as correct to put this to bed. Cheers!